# Canvas Coordinates

Tags: canvas, mouse, coordinates

So I'm new to Html/Javascript. So I decided to play around with the canvas and display tiles and get mouse clicks. What I'm trying to do is get the mouse click, and turn the tile that the user clicked on to be changed colors. The problem is the way I'm getting where the user clicked to be converted onto tile coordinates. It seems that the farther down right I go the less accurate it gets too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Fun Canvas!!!</title>
    <style>
        canvas 
        {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
            border:1px solid #000000;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        // Map Related
        var m_iTotalWidth;
        var m_iTotalHeight;
        var m_iMapWidth = 60;
        var m_iMapHeight = 30;
        var m_iTileWidth;
        var m_iTileHeight;
        var m_bColorFull = new Array(m_iMapWidth);
        var m_cColors = ['#FF0000', '#FF7700', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00', '#1500FF', '#C700FF'];
        var m_cDefaultColor = "#000";
        var m_CanvaContext;
        var m_Canvas;
        var m_iBorderLength = 1;

        // Map Color related
        var iMin = 0;
        var iMax = 255;
        var m_iPrevX = 0;
        var m_iPrevY = 0;

        // GameSpeed
        var m_iGameSpeed = 60;

        var m_IntervalID;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
        document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden';     // horizontal scrollbar will be hidden
        document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'hidden';

        function initialize() {
            m_IntervalID = window.setInterval("gameLoop();", m_iGameSpeed);

            // Get canvas context for drawing
            m_CanvasContext = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
            setCanvasSize();
            m_Canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', getPosition, false);

            for (var x = 0; x < m_iMapWidth; x++) {
                m_bColorFull[x] = new Array(m_iMapHeight);

                for (var y = 0; y < m_iMapHeight; y++)
                {
                    if (y == 0)
                        paintTile(x, y, "white", 2);

                    m_bColorFull[x][y] = false;
                }
            }

            drawMap();
            gameLoop();
        }

        // Runs all the functions required for the game to work.
        function gameLoop() {
            drawMap();
        }

        // Draws everything on the canvas.
        function drawMap() {

            for (var x = 0; x < m_iMapWidth; x++)
                for (var y = 1; y < m_iMapHeight; y++) {

                    if (m_bColorFull[x][y])
                        paintTile(x, y, getRandomColor(0, 255), 2);

                    else
                        paintTile(x, y, m_cDefaultColor, 2);
                }
        }

        // Paints a tile on the screen, handles converting pixel to tile.
        function paintTile(x, y, color, borderThickness) 
        {
            m_CanvasContext.fillStyle = color;
            m_CanvasContext.fillRect((x * m_iTileWidth) + borderThickness, (y * m_iTileHeight) + borderThickness, m_iTileWidth - (borderThickness * 2), m_iTileHeight - (borderThickness * 2));
        }

        // Handles clicks.
        function getPosition(event)
        {
            var rect = m_Canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
            x = Math.round(x / m_iTileWidth);
            y = Math.round(y / m_iTileHeight);

            for (var xIndex = 0; xIndex < m_iMapWidth; xIndex++)
                for (var yIndex = 0; yIndex < 1; yIndex++)
                    paintTile(xIndex, yIndex, "white", 0);

            writeMessage(1, "black", x + "-" + y);
            m_bColorFull[x][y] = !m_bColorFull[x][y];
        }

        // Sets the canvas as big as the broswer size.
        function setCanvasSize()
        {
            m_CanvasContext.scale(1, 1);
            m_iTileWidth = Math.floor(m_CanvasContext.canvas.width / m_iMapWidth);//Math.floor(window.innerWidth / m_iMapWidth);
            m_iTileHeight = Math.floor(m_CanvasContext.canvas.height / m_iMapHeight); //Math.floor(window.innerHeight / m_iMapHeight);
            //m_CanvasContext.canvas.width = (m_iTileWidth * m_iMapWidth);
            //m_CanvasContext.canvas.height = (m_iTileHeight * m_iMapHeight);
        }

        function writeMessage(startTile, color, message) 
        {
            m_CanvasContext.font = '16pt Calibri';
            m_CanvasContext.fillStyle = color;
            m_CanvasContext.fillText(message, startTile * m_iTileWidth, 16);
        }
        /*********************************************************************************************************/
        /*USEFULL FUNCTIONS*/

        function getRandomColor(iMin, iMax) {

            //return m_cColors[getRandomNumber(0, m_cColors.length)];
            // creating a random number between iMin and iMax
            var r = getRandomNumber(iMin, iMax)
            var g = getRandomNumber(iMin, iMax)
            var b = getRandomNumber(iMin, iMax)

            // going from decimal to hex
            var hexR = r.toString(16);
            var hexG = g.toString(16);
            var hexB = b.toString(16);

            // making sure single character values are prepended with a "0"
            if (hexR.length == 1)
                hexR = "0" + hexR;

            if (hexG.length == 1)
                hexG = "0" + hexG;

            if (hexB.length == 1)
                hexB = "0" + hexB;

            // creating the hex value by concatenatening the string values
            var hexColor = "#" + hexR + hexG + hexB;
            return hexColor.toUpperCase();
        }

        function getRandomNumber(iMin, iMax) {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * (iMax - iMin)) + iMin);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm making something very similar but I'm having the same problem and none of these answers have helped. I've literally tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've did this already: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/rJD3r/

and explained in detail here: https://ijosephblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/implementing-conways-game-of-life-in-html5-canvas-with-javascript/

There's much more stuff to what you really need, so here I've made a simpler version: http://jsfiddle.net/DTMRt/

This chunk of code from the demo above converts mouse coordinates into an array index.

```
var j = Math.floor((g.mouseX / (dim + spacing)));
var i = Math.floor(g.mouseY / (dim + spacing));
grid[j][i] = "mouse is passing over here!";
```

where `dim` is the dimension of a tile, `spacing` is the distance between the tiles (you can set that to zero) and g.mouseX/g.mouseY are the mouse coordinates.

You need all your tiles to be in an array of arrays, I did it like this:

```
var grid = new Array(grid_width);

for (var j = 0; j<grid_width; j++){
grid[j] = new Array(grid_height);
};
```

where grid_width and grid_height will be number of rows and columns of tiles.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
update = function(){
canvas.onmousedown=function(){
var e = window.event;
var posX = e.clientX;
var posY = e.clientY;
```

> alert("X position: "+ posX + " Y position: " + posY);`

```
};
setInterval(update,100);
```

Does it work for you?